# SQL Stored Procedure WHERE item is not in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table like so:

```
DECLARE @deadCommunityList TABLE (community VARCHAR(12))
INSERT INTO @deadCommunityList (community)
VALUES ('000')
    , ('253'), ('COU'), ('COV')
    , ('D2T'), ('D3T'), ('DEW')
    , ('DIT'), ('E2T'), ('E3T')
    , ('EL2'), ('EL3'), ('ELC')
    , ('ELI'), ('ELT'), ('ERI')
    , ('FA1'), ('GRA'), ('GRD')
    , ('GRT'), ('HIG'), ('HIP')
    , ('LYN'), ('NEW'), ('PAR')
    , ('PMT'), ('RDT'), ('RES')
    , ('SCR'), ('SCT'), ('SMT')
    , ('SUM'), ('TB'), ('W2T')
    , ('WDV'), ('WE2'), ('WIC')
    , ('WEC'), ('WIL'), ('ZIT')
```

and now I have this query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AREA_DESC
FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES
WHERE AREA_ID NOT IN @deadCommunityList
ORDER BY AREA_DESC
```

What I am trying to say is give me the results where AREA_ID is not in the table....this is not working, I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@deadCommunityList".

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@deadCommunityList` is Table variable

Comment: The statement are in the same StoredProcedure or they are in different points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AREA_DESC 
FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES 
WHERE AREA_ID NOT IN (SELECT community FROM @deadCommunityList)
ORDER BY AREA_DESC
```

`@deadCommunityList` is a *table* variable, so you have to `SELECT` from its values.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @deadCommunityList TABLE (
    community VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY --WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)
)

INSERT INTO @deadCommunityList
...

SELECT DISTINCT AREA_DESC
FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES
WHERE AREA_ID NOT IN (SELECT e.community FROM @deadCommunityList е)
ORDER BY AREA_DESC
--OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: using wildchar in (SELECT * FROM @deadCommunityList) is a really bad habit. If this was a real table and the table had another column added, your query would become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You should use subselect in `where` condition since `@deadCommunityList` is table variable.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AREA_DESC 
FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES 
WHERE AREA_ID NOT IN (select community from @deadCommunityList)
ORDER BY AREA_DESC
```

Alternatively you can join to this table variable and get only records from `V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES` which has no matched records from `@deadCommunityList`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.AREA_DESC 
FROM V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES as T
    left outer join @deadCommunityList as T1 on T1.community = T.AREA_ID
WHERE T1.community is null
ORDER BY T.AREA_DESC
```